# How to redirect mdfind output to if else statament in bash

Tags: bash, output

I am trying to create a script that look for some files, listed in an input file, all over the computer and then copy those files in a specific folder.
So far all ok with a for loop and mdfind "command" | xargs.
But the if i add an if statement to create an output file with the list of the files that mdfind didn't find, here comes the problems.
Here is my actual code:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Please introduce the name of the input file after runnig the command. 
For this script you need an INPUT.txt file containing only the list of the 
samples you want to copy." 
else
for i in $(cat $1); 
do mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == $i*.ab1" | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' 
/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/test_moving/; 
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
echo $i >> extractions_not_found.txt
else
echo $i >> extractions_found.txt
fi
done
fi
```

I am using $? to redirect the output of

```
 mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == $i*.ab1" | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/test_moving/;
```

but it is alway = 0, even when it cant find the one file listed in the input file.

Anyone can help me understand where is the error??

Thank you!

Comment: This is because `$?` is getting the exit code of `xargs`, not of `cp` or `mdfind`.

Answer (score 1):

After you run `mdfind ... | xargs cp ...`, the error code in `$?` is that of `xargs`, since it's the last command in the pipeline. `xargs` returns 123 if any command it executed failed, but if `mdfind` doesn't produce any output, then `xargs` doesn't do anything, so it also doesn't fail.

However, in Bash, you can find the exit codes of all commands in the last pipeline in the [array variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) `PIPESTATUS`. The exit code of the first command is `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` etc.

```
$ false | true | xargs false
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[*]}"
1 0 123
```

So, instead of using `$?`, which gives you the exit status of `xargs`, you could use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` giving you the exit status of `mdfind`. Or save the lot to another variable and test both. (`saved=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")`)

Alternatively, use `set -o pipefail` so that `$?` gives you the exit code of last failing command of the pipeline, if any of them fail. (`false | true` would result in `$?=1`.)

Comment: You can also `set -o pipefail` and `set -e`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, ah `pipefail` of course, thanks. `set -e` only helps here with pipefail, but I don't think they want that at all.

Comment: so i did the echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} and this is how it looks like:                0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0                                      
so basically is always 0 even if is not copying any file because mdfind didn't found (in my case i have an input file with 5 files to look for and the last file doesn't exist on my computer so cant be find and/or copied)